Grid 4 PHP does not show pager on top
This is my PHP code:
include(PHPGRID_LIBPATH . "inc/jqgrid_dist.php");
$db_conf = array(
    "type"      => PHPGRID_DBTYPE,
    "server"    => PHPGRID_DBHOST,
    "user"      => PHPGRID_DBUSER,
    "password"  => PHPGRID_DBPASS,
    "database"  => PHPGRID_DBNAME
);

$g = new jqgrid($db_conf);
$opt["autowidth"] = true;
$opt["forceFit"] = true;
$opt["rownumbers"] = true;
$opt["rownumWidth"] = 50;
$opt["rowNum"] = 20;
$opt["autoresize"] = true;
$opt["resizable"] = false;
$opt["altRows"] = true;
$opt["height"] = "100%";
$opt["toolbar"] = "top";
$opt["toppager"] = true;
$opt["pgbuttons"] = true;

$g->table = $nav;
$g->set_options($opt);
$g->set_actions(array(
    "autofilter" => false,
    "export" => true,
    "search" => "simple",
    "export_excel" => true,
    "export_pdf" => true,
    "export_csv" => true,
    "export_html" => true,
));

$table = $g->render("table");

and HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="lib/js/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" integrity="sha384-4LISF5TTJX/fLmGSxO53rV4miRxdg84mZsxmO8Rx5jGtp/LbrixFETvWa5a6sESd" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-Fb0zP4jE3JHqu+IBB9YktLcSjI1Zc6J2b6gTjB0LpoM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="lib/js/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col py-3">
    <?php echo $table ?>
</div>
</body>

I cannot add a working snippet since I was not able to find a CDN for Grid 4 PHP.
From the options listed here I expect to have the toolbar placed on top (correct) with the pager controls. Instead they are not there:

If I place the toolbar on bottom side, the pager controls are available.
How to have the pager controls on top side as well?

To enable the pager on top, you need to add the following style code:
<style>
    .ui-jqgrid div[id$=_toppager] > div > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) { display:revert !important;}
    .ui-jqgrid div[id$=_toppager] > div > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) { display:revert !important;}
</style>

